# Order a list on page by LastName in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C# and I am trying to figure out how to Order the candidate list on the candidates index page by LastName in the Candidates controlle, here is the code:

```
    // GET: Candidates
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var applicationDbContext = _context.Candidate.Include(c => c.Job);
        return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var applicationDbContext = _context.Candidate.Include(c => c.Job).OrderBy(l => l.LastName);
```

Comment: Thank You ! It worked. Can I ask one more question? I have to change the detail view so the Job Name field is a link to the related Job’s detail page. Here is the code:                                        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Job.Name)
        </dd>

Comment: Search for something that uses the Models data to construct a Link/Url in the View, <dd class = "col-sm-10"> **<a href="~/Route/" + model.Job.Id>Job Detail for** @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Job.Name) **</a>** </dd>